# Create a movie clip using a map

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I want to create a map of the Brazil out of it's elements, i.e. states, and I find it really confusing from where to start in CS5. Does anyone know how can I make movie clips states out of map, 'cause drawing the lines isn't that thrilling at all.

It may sound like a dump Q. but I am a starter in coding in AS, so I think you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, I would either ..
1. Get/Buy a vector version of the map divided in to sections and then select those sections and make movieclips out of them
2. use Yahoo Maps
3. use Google Maps
Otherwise you will need to redraw or get it in WMA, EPS, AI format

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take a screenshot of a map of Brazil, place it on a layer with low opacity and then trace over it on another layer using the pencil/pen?

Could even create a new layer for each state for ease down the track.

[image]

Alternatively: http://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?id=46675381